# Limiting the maximum request size in Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, spring-boot

Working on a REST service based on Spring Boot with an embedded Tomcat I would like to limit the size of the request body for any HTTP method (POST, PUT, GET, ...).

I know of the `maxPostSize` property of a connector. But this property seems to limit only POST requests. Another possibility IMHO is to implement `javax.servlet.Filter` and to check the value of the Content-Length header.

Is there another way to achieve this that I am not aware of?

Comment: GET doesn't have request body...

Comment: @kryger This is a common misbelief. It is possible - but unusual - to do a GET with a request body. ElasticSearch is one system which uses this feature.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. Another day, another interesting thing learned.

Answer (score 1):

You may [set the multipart.maxRequestSize property](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/MultipartConfigFactory.html) in application.properties. The [default is 10Mb](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.html).

Comment: It does help in my case. For some reasons I am able to do POST requests with an request body of 20M.